# *ngFor doesn't display second component without detectChanges()

Tags: angular, conditional-rendering, angular-ngfor, change-detector-ref

I'm trying to display other component in my app with *ngFor. It doesn't render if I don't use detectChanges() in my method. Should it be like that?

```
 <button class="custom-button" (click)="showHide()">
     DISPLAY COMPONENT
 </button>
 <div *ngIf="visibleSecondComponent>
     <app-second-component></app-second-component>
 </div>
```

My method:

```
showHide() {
   this.visibleSecondComponent= !this.visibleSecondComponent;
   // this.changeDetectorRef.detectChanges();
   console.log('show ' + this.visibleSecondComponent);
}
```

When I comment out this.changeDetectorRef.detectChanges(); it doesn't render , but in the console I see it is working and it prints out the console.log.

What is the cause of that behavior? I have similar issue when I want to use | async.
I'm using angular 13.2.0

I would appreciate some hints if it's a normal behavior or am I doing something wrong.

Comment: What is the change detection strategy of the component? If it is `OnPush`, it will not detect this kind of changes until you manually trigger.

Comment: @HarunYilmaz It seems like it is OnPush, but I didn't specified it anywhere... So that's why I'm confused. Can I fix it somehow to detect changes without changeDetectorRef?

Comment: I used now changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.Default, but it also doesn't work

Comment: Can you reproduce your issue with stackblitz?

Comment: missing a `"` at teh end of you ngIf but i assume this is just example code of the problem

Comment: Yes it is just an example. 

Sorry I cannot reproduce it (tried). This is a microfrontend app - I'm not sure if that is the cause. If it won't work I will just stick with detectChanges()

Comment: I resolved it :) there was mix within modules. Thanks for answears!